# not able to see table under server explorer

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I cant see the table that I have created under server explorer I restarted refreshed and created a whole new project.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G8oie.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YtpoX.png)

Comment: Are you looking in the correct MDF?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can refer the following steps, if you want to see table under server explorer.

First, you can create a new table as before.
[image]

Second, you shoule click Updata and Update Database.
[image]

Then right click on your database and choose Refresh.

[image]

Finally you will see the table under server explorer.